# What happens if a function takes a parameter that overlaps with a global (same name) variable?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, parameters, global

Another javascript 101 question, but here goes:

```
var iamglobal='yep, im global';
function test(iamglobal){
    ...
}
test('overlapage boh!');
```

In this situation, what happens with iamglobal?

Comment: What is the point of asking if you can easily try that out?

Comment: while i understand that all of this can be checked via chromes console or firebug... i thought i would ask to know the actual "technical" name for what happens here... and that i got... "variable is shadowed"...

Answer (score 1):

The global `iamglobal` variable is *shadowed* by the local `iamglobal` variable.

They exist independent from each other, but the global cannot be reached from the function scope, only the local variable will be affected when the `iamglobal` identifier is used.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing. The body of the function has simply lost the ability to refer to the global variable because the argument's name hides it.